# Spark sum and DecimalType precision

Tags: apache-spark

Observation: Spark `sum` seems to increase the precision of `DecimalType` arguments by 10.

```
scala> val df1 = spark.sql("select(cast(1 as decimal(4,0))) as foo")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [foo: decimal(4,0)]

scala> df1.select(sum($"foo").as("bar"))
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [bar: decimal(14,0)]
```

Questions:

- where is this documented?
- Is there some configuration setting where the default of `10` can be overridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be hardcoded in the source code, as an optimization for `SUM` and `AVG` aggregates:

[source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/02d3b3b452892779b3f0df7018a9574fde02afee/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L1876)

Additional info on [DecimalAggregates](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-Optimizer-DecimalAggregates.html)

`SUM` will add 10 to the precision, `AVG` will add 4 to the precision AND scale if optimization is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented under [`DataTypes.createDecimalType`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataTypes.java#L129):

```
/**
 * Creates a DecimalType with default precision and scale, which are 10 and 0.
 */
 public static DecimalType createDecimalType() {
   return DecimalType$.MODULE$.USER_DEFAULT();
 }
```

When a decimal is created, the default overload is used ([there's also one which directly accepts scale and precision](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataTypes.java#L129))

You can modify the scale by casting:

```
df1.select(sum($"foo").as("bar")).cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(4, 0))
```

Comment: I wasn't asking about the default DecimalType but the behavior of `sum` specifically which returns `DecimalType(p+10, s)` given input of `DecimalType(p,s)`